# Uniqueness of your PC comparing Tor vs JonDo

Tags: jondonym

When checking my PC on Panopticlick, I could see that even using Tor does not make my PC more anonymous...

...using JonDo, however, and visiting Panopticlick, my PC was less identifiably unique than when using Tor.

JonDo mentions things like using different fonts.

Is it possible for Tor to make similar changes so that your PC is less identifiable?

I'm not a computer geek, so maybe I'm getting something wrong here?

P.S. I tagged this post with "tag" because I was not allowed to use relevant tags, like JonDo, Uniqueness, Identifiable, Fonts etc.

==================================================================================

re  two answers so far:

"Try JonDoFox with Tor"? > Meaning? In what way? They're two separate browsers.

"Tor Browser also erases browser uniqueness, but maybe it leaks more than JonDoFox" >
My test was using each browser at Panopticlick. Tor's access showed that my PC was unique. Following the advice in the 2nd reply, below, I change a font and had my anonymity marginally improved. JonDo's access significantly improved my identifiability...i.e. more computers like mine when accessing that site. Roya's link to JonDo test is where I got info re fonts from beforehand. It mentioned choosing Arial, Sans serif and Helvetica (from memory) as ones to choose. Only see Arial though in settings.

As stated, I'm not tech minded. Not sure how Tor's/JonDo's safety re IP address hangs with issue of how identifiable your PC is. In other words, if your IP address is not your own, is that protection enough? What if a site can see that you have a unique computer? What about MAC idenitifiablity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/what-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-tor-with-respect-to-jondonym)?

Answer (score 2):

Try JonDoFox with Tor. JonDo does nothing to make your PC less identifiable, but the JonDoFox extension works hard to erase the differences between firefox instances so your browser is less identifiable (They even fixed the WebRTC STUN leak in the latest JonDoFox). Tor Browser  also erases browser uniqueness, but maybe it leaks more than JonDoFox.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you put your fingure on the Achilles heel, If you try this web site: http://ip-check.info/?lang=en   while using Tor Browser and proceed to look at Fonts, you can see a warning. For more detail look at this Question: [Even after disabling Java Script Fonts are readable. Is there any patch for this issue?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/even-after-disabling-java-script-fonts-are-readable-is-there-any-patch-for-this)

Also look at the answer provided by Rhin, in addition read the comments below this answer. You may have a good point. There were some attempt to alleviate the problem, but I am not sure it is enough.

> If your IP address is not your own, is that protection enough.

It may or may not be depending on the situation. For example if the IP address is your aunt's and you live with her, it is definitely not. If the IP address is for example Starbucks coffee company's and you live in a crowded metropolitian area like NewYork city or Tokyo and there is no security camera, recording with a time-stamp of who comes and who goes, you maybe in a better situation. But ultimately, you are better off using a laptop with the OS, browser, fonts, etc. this not unique; so that if everything else fails, you still are not identifiable. For as close to a comprehensive answer as I have seem look at this Q&A:  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43369/best-practices-for-tor-use-in-light-of-released-nsa-slides